# Dúvida sobre performance de query com intervalo de datas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Supondo que eu tenho uma tabela do banco de dados com 10000 dados e cada registro esta cadastrado com datas entre 2013 e 2014.

Uma query assim:

```
SELECT CAMPO_DATA FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO_DATA BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
```

será mais rápida do que:

```
SELECT CAMPO_DATA FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO_DATA BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2100-12-31'
```

?

Caso eu use da segunda forma isso pode afetar muito a velocidade da query caso a tabela tenha muitos itens?

Fico em dúvida pois não sei se o sql primeiro vê qual o intervalo de datas que a tabela possui ou se ele vai percorrendo de acordo com os limites que eu estabeleci.

Comment: Uma tabela pequena como esta o BD provavelmente "come com farinha" , mas se a tabela for grande (milhões de registros) aí a coisa muda de figura. No segundo caso talvez fosse o caso de nem ter condição where mas pode ser um caso de uma busta parametrizada e aí valeca pena ter um só SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Caso 1: CAMPO_DATA não possui índice

O plano de execução será em cima da tabela toda ([TABLE SCAN](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181129(v=sql.105).aspx)). Para ambas as consultas, o tempo será o mesmo.

## Caso 2: CAMPO_DATA possui índice

O plano de execução poderá será em cima do índice ou não. Tudo depende das estatísticas já calculadas do banco de dados.

Se for em cima de índice, a primeira sentença é mais rápida, pois o plano de execução ficará em cima de uma partição da tabela mapeada pelo índice, e não da tabela inteira.

Se não for em cima de índice, os tempos novamente serão os mesmos.

Answer (score 0):

Se todos os dados do BD estão entre essas datas , tanto faz uma forma ou outra, agora se esse é o caso, não vejo necessidade desse where